# Chemical Potentials and Phase Changes

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, chemical-potential

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy) for the Helmholtz free energy has a derivation showing that if the volume and temperature of a system are kept constant, then
$$W \leq - \Delta F$$
Where $W$ is the work performed *by* the system (i.e. the work that can be extracted). If $W=0,$ then
$$\Delta F \leq 0.$$

It then reads

> This result seems to contradict the equation $dF = −S dT − P dV$, as keeping $T$ and $V$ constant seems to imply $dF = 0$, and hence $F =$ constant. In reality there is no contradiction: In a simple one-component system, to which the validity of the equation $dF = −S dT − P dV$ is restricted, no process can occur at constant $T$ and $V$, since there is a unique $P(T, V)$ relation, and thus $T, V$, and $P$ are all fixed. To allow for spontaneous processes at constant $T$ and $V$, one needs to enlarge the thermodynamical state space of the system. In case of a chemical reaction, one must allow for changes in the numbers $N_j$ of particles of each type $j$.

I want to understand how this plays out in practice. So, for example, I will consider a tub of water held in contact with a thermal reservoir of $0^\circ$ C, and held at constant shape (and thus volume). Suppose I have an electric coil which allows me to do electrical work on the water. Supposing my initial tub of water has some ice in it. Then as I do electrical work on the water the ice changes to liquid water.

Question: Would the correct way to model this be to treat the ice and water as two different species, $N_{\text{ice}}$ and $N_{\text{liquid}}$, with two different chemical potentials? If so, which of the two would have a higher chemical potential? I would imagine that we have $W'=\Delta F \geq 0$ where $W'$ is the work done *on* the system. This implies that the liquid water has a higher chemical potential, and that
$$\Delta F = \Delta N_{\text{ice}} \mu_{\text{ice}} + \Delta N_{\text{liquid}} \mu_{\text{liquid}}$$

Question: Would it be possible in this scenario (constant temperature, constant volume) to *extract* energy from the system instead?

Question: Are the chemical potentials of ice and water dependent on temperature? For example, in the scenario where we had water in thermal equilibrium with a reservoir at $10^\circ$ C, we would not expect the liquid to spontaneously turn into ice, even though this would decrease $\Delta F.$ So does this mean that in this case the chemical potential of ice is *higher* than liquid water?

Question: Are there any other simple models like this which describe a change in $F?$

Question: Imagine a two species intially separated, but then allowed to mix. Suppose the temperature and volume are held constant. In this case $N=$ constant for both species - does $F$ *decrease*? Does this imply the chemical potential per particle decreases?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to understand the inequality $\Delta F \leq 0$ is through a partitioned system, such that the total volume and total mass are constant, and all parts have the same temperature. Your example of ice and water is not going to work unless they are both at the same temperature.

The proper example is to take a system made of two parts as in the picture below.

[image]

The parts are in a bath that keeps the temperature constant. The total volume and total moles are fixed. Start with some $N_1$ and $V_1$ in part 1 and put the rest ($N_2=N-N_1$, $V_2=V-V_1$) in part $V$. Each part is in internal equilibrium so that we can calculate the free energy $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Now transfer a small amount of volume $\delta V$ or mass $\delta N$ from part 1 to part 2 and recalculate the new free energies, $F_1'$ and $F_2'$. If the change,
$$
   \Delta F = F_1'+F_2'-F_1-F_2
$$
is *negative*, then we have taken a step closer to equilibrium. If it is positive, we are moving away from equilibrium, which means we should reverse the direction of $\delta N$, $\delta V$. To reach equilibrium keep exchanging volume and mass so that the total free energy decreases. When it cannot decrease any more, i.e., $\Delta F = 0$ with respect to all small exchanges, then we have reached equilibrium.

The mathematical condition that minimizes the total free energy is
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial V_1}\right)_{T,N_1}  
   =   
   \left(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial V_2}\right)_{T,N_2}
  \Rightarrow P_1 = P_2 
  \\ 
   \left(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial N_1}\right)_{T,V_1}  
   =   
   \left(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial N_2}\right)_{T,V_2}
   \Rightarrow \mu_1 = \mu_2 
$$
which leads to the equilibrium conditions of equal pressure and equal chemical potential.

If we were to collect the $PV$ work during these exchanges and the chemical work $\mu dN$, their sum would be $\Delta F$, the free change in free energy from the initial state to equilibrium.

Comment: Hello, thank you. This is informative. The question is closed - so I might just accept this answer, but I do have one more question if you are interested:  Can you describe a mechanism by which it would be possible to extract the energy from chemical work $\mu dN$ and use it to do some type of useful work? Additionally, if you find any of the my original questions answerable that would be appreciated.

Comment: The osmotic experiment is one example of chemical work converted into useful work: Solvent mixes with a solution of a solute via a membrane permeable only to the solvent, and as a result it increases the  hydrostatic pressure on the solution side. Another example is an electrochemical reaction, which converts Gibbs energy into electric work. (Edit your question to focus it, as per suggestion, and hopefully it will be reopened).